# EXT JS , how to delete record from the grid

Tags: extjs

I have a task to make simple app in EXT JS.

I was given public api, that should fill my table with data. REST PROXY has been used, type of files is JSON.

I have table, everything is working and now I have to delete locally some records from table.

Delete process should happen when I click on small icon like a bin. 
I made that icon, when you press it, it opens alert, asking you do you want to delete that record?

Now, thing is, if you click yes it should remove record, and close the window. 
But now nothing happens.

I have defined, model, store, main controller.
How to implement such method in a way it delete recored localy.

I have tried different methods, but nothing worked. 
When I click yes it just closes window.

How to solve this issues with having 3 constructors for 3 objects, and hwo to create delete method properly so it can delete record locally??

If there is somenone who is experienced with EXT framework, I would be really tankful..

This is giving me nigthmares...

```
******This is main controller ::******


Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.main',

    onItemSelected: function (sender, record) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure?', 'onConfirm', this);
    },

    OnEdit: function (sender, records, data, result,FullName ) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Edit', 'Edit' + " " + ["0"].records);
    },


    OnDelete: function(sender, records) {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Changes', 'Do you want to delete' + " " + records)
    },

    AddRecord: function(sender, record) {
        Ext.Msg.form( )

    },

    onConfirm: function (choice,) {
        if (choice === 'yes') {
       store.remove(records);   
        }
    }
});
```

******THIS IS STORE: *********************

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Personnel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.personnel',
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: null,

    model: 'Personnel',

    proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    method:{ 
    read: 'GET',
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'data',

    }

   },
   listeners: {
    load: function( store, records,) {
      console.log(records);

    }
}
   });
```

******And this is List.js******

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainlist',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.Personnel',

    ],

    title: 'Personnel',

    store: {
        type: 'personnel'
    },

    actions: {

        edit: {
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-pencil-square',
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            handler: 'OnEdit'
        },

        delete: {
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash-o',
            text: 'Delete',
            handler: 'OnDelete'
        }
    },

    columns: [
        { text: '', dataIndex: 'avatar', renderer: function (value) { return '<img src="' + value + '" width="32" height="32" borer="0" />'; } },
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'FullName', flex: 1 },
        { text: "Active", dataIndex: 'active', xtype: 'checkcolumn' },
        {
            text: 'Action', dataIndex: 'action', xtype: 'actioncolumn', flex: 1,
            items: ['@edit', '@delete'],
        }
    ],
    tbar: [
        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Add Record', cls: 'x-btn-default-small', handler: 'AddRecord'}
    ],

    form: {

        fields:{  
            text: 'First Name',
            text: 'Last Name',
        },
    },
    listeners: {
        select: 'onItemSelected',
    }
});
```

I have objects like this... How can I change this???

```
(3) [constructor, constructor, constructor]
0: constructor {data: {…}, session: null, internalId: 4, id: 1, phantom: false, …}
1: constructor {data: {…}, session: null, internalId: 5, id: 2, phantom: false, …}
2: constructor {data: {…}, session: null, internalId: 6, id: 3, phantom: false, …}
length: 3
```

Comment: Did you try using `store.commitChanges()` after line `store.remove(records)`?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, it's not deleting record from the grid at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to acces Object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083847/how-to-acces-object-property)

Answer (score 0):

Your OnDelete function don't have store so how to delete the data? You have another problem with Ext.Msg.confirm. You do not specify a function

By docs - confirm ( title, message, [fn], [scope] ) : Ext.window.MessageBox

try this

```
OnDelete: function(sender, records) {
   Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Changes', 'Do you want to delete', function(choice){
        if (choice === 'yes') {

            //declare store and remove records 

            store.remove(records);   
        }   
   });
```

Comment: Did that, nothing happened.. :(

Comment: var store = Ext.getStore('store.personnel');
                store.remove(record);

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2trt 

look at this example. i used store.removeAll() - this function removeAll record from store 
change from store.remove(records) 
ma

if it works let me know

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined

Comment: OnDelete: function (record,data) {
     Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Changes', 'Do you want to delete' + " " + record.Details, function (choice) {
        
            if (choice === 'yes') {
                var store = Ext.getStore('Personnel');
                store.remove(record);
                store.sync();

            }
        })
    },

Comment: Your store is it correctly defined? Maybe try this on console.log(store) after store definition.