# How to acces Object property

Tags: extjs

I have external API, 
proxy is rest,
reader defined, 
type: 'json',
rootProperty: 'data;

How to get property "FullName"
I have tried with record.get('FullName').

Created function called getDetails, passed as argument string, returned 
return record.get('FullName), always undefined.

```
 Details: function(v, record) {

       return record.get('FullName') 
    }
```

Here is onDelete function :

```
OnDelete: function (record,data) {
     Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Changes', 'Do you want to delete' + " " + record.Details, function (choice) {

            if (choice === 'yes') {
                var store = Ext.getStore('store.Personnel');
                store.remove(record);
                store.sync();

            }
        })
    },
```

[this is how console log on record look like. 
I have 3 constructors with Id's then data, and then obj properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT3te.png))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use record.get('FullName') like:

```
OnDelete: function (grid, rowId) {
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowId);
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Delete Changes', 'Do you want to delete' + " " + record.get('FullName'), function (choice) {
            if (choice === 'yes') {
                var store = grid.getStore();
                console.log(store)
                store.remove(record);

            }
        })
    }
```

Your example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ttb

Comment: Ext.define('MyApp.store.Personnel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        alias: 'store.personnel',
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: null,
    
        model: 'Personnel',
    
        proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
        method:{ 
        read: 'GET',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty:'data',
           
        }
        
       },
       listeners: {
        load: function( store, records,) {
          console.log(records);
    
        }
    }
       });

Comment: In Model, I have field "FullName". I'm using convert function, to get full name. Since I have first and last name fields as well, and I want to display full name, I had to use convert function. It reads data from reader and convert that string in object.

Comment: Can you attach the provided arguments to `OnDelete` method: record and data ?

Comment: Here is the link for the store and whole project.
https://github.com/MrNoOne007/EXT-JS---App/blob/master/app/store/Personnel.js

Comment: Better attach the example on fiddle to easy recreate, in referenced github project i don't see view with usage of `OnDelete` method.

Comment: I am totally new to EXT JS. 
Everything is displayed on List.js, no separate view, and OnDelete method is located in the maincontroller. 
I will try to create fiddle, I've never used it before. 
Thanks for trying to help me out here : ) and for your patience.

Comment: Check my answer - you need to update the `OnDelete` method.

Comment: I've tried this method, and then I get an error like record.get('FullName') is not a function. :(
That is the reason why I created details function, to try to return record.get('FullName") and then just call that function inside OnDelete method.
But then I got undefined.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I started using EXT JS a few days ago.  
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks bro, it is working! :) It shows Full name.. 
 But I still have that error about
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined. 
How it cannot read property remove?

Comment: Solved,  error was Ext.getStore, it should be grid.getStore..
 var store = Ext.getStore('store.Personnel'); error
var store = grid.getStore('store.Personnel'); working

Comment: In fiddle i didn't require `font awesome` package - so you can't use `x-fa icon`. If question is solved by my answer, accept the answer as a solution